# yii2 : remove comma from createCommand

Tags: mysql, yii2-advanced-app

i've create a Command in my controller like this :

```
public function actionTotal($id)
{
     $query1 = new Query;
     $query1  ->select('sum(patient_services.price) price, sum(receipts.price) receipts ,') 
         ->from('patient_services  ')
         ->leftJoin('  receipts  ON patient_services.patient_id=receipts.patient_id')
         ->where('patient_services.patient_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id));         
     $command1 = $query1->createCommand();
     $price = $command1->queryAll();  
     echo Json::encode($price);
}
```

when i try it ...  the select code have a comma and idon't know how to remove it

```
 SELECT sum(patient_services.price) price, sum(receipts.price) receipts FROM `patient_services` LEFT JOIN `  receipts  ON` `patient_services`.`patient_id=receipts`.`patient_id` WHERE patient_services.patient_id=1
```

when i remove all commas from the sql code and try it in phpmyadmin .. it works fine :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid leftJoin replace it with this:

```
->leftJoin('receipts', 'patient_services.patient_id = receipts.patient_id')
```

also it seems you have an extra comma at the end of your select query remove that last comma the select query would look like this:

```
$query1  ->select('sum(patient_services.price) price, sum(receipts.price) receipts')
```

Hope this works.

Comment: thank you very much it works fine ,,,  but i have a new problem  how can I  add  IFNull to my command  ?

Comment: $query1->select([' sum(patient_services.price) price , sum( IFNULL(receipts.price,0)) receipts'])